# How to get variable from def function to global?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I've defined a function, but I 'm not able to call the variable from define function to `global`.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
def pdf_btnClicked():
    PathOfPDF = askopenfile()
    PDFFILE = PathOfPDF.name
    print(PDFFILE)

book = open(PDFFILE, 'rb')
```

Comment: You need to add `global PDFFILE` as the first line of your function.

Comment: Apart from the global issue, better use `askopenfilename()` instead of `askopenfile()` if you just want the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correct code**

```
def pdf_btnClicked():
    global PDFFILE
    PathOfPDF = askopenfile()
    PDFFILE = PathOfPDF.name
    print(PDFFILE)
    
book = open(PDFFILE, 'rb')
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are using Python, you can use the `global` keyword when declaring a variable on a local scope. Using it will make your variable goes global and your code will look like this:

```
def pdf_btnClicked():
   global PDFFILE
   PathOfPDF = askopenfile()
   PDFFILE = PathOfPDF.name
   print(PDFFILE)

book = open(PDFFILE, 'rb')
```

Looking at the code we can inferir that your problem is related to the concept of variable scope.

A scope in any programming is a region of the program where a defined variable can have its existence and beyond that variable it cannot be accessed. Basicaly there are two type of variable regarding it's scope:

1. Inside a function or a block which is called **local variables**

In this case, if you declare a varible inside a function, you wont be able to use it outside that function. That's exactly your case: you declared the variable `PDFFILE`  inside the `pdf_btnClicked` function so you will only be able to use the variable inside that. But even so, you are calling the variable outside it. A basic solution for your problem is to so set `PDFFILE`  as global variable, whose explanation follows bellow.

2. Outside of all functions which is called **global variables**

Global variables, as the name suggest, are global and can be accessed by all function. If you declare `PDFFILE`  outside the function (and before it) your problem will be solved

Obs.: here we saw the two basics types of variables's scope but it's possible to have more than only two depending on the programming language

Fonts: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Comment: Not sure why you are linking to a tutorial on *C* scoping rules. Python's scoping rules may be similar but there are some key differences that you won't get from knowing C's rules.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `global` keyword.

```py
PDFFILE = ""
def pdf_btnClicked():
    global PDFFILE
    PathOfPDF = askopenfile()
    PDFFILE = PathOfPDF.name
    print(PDFFILE)

# You need to call `pdf_btnClicked()` function
book = open(PDFFILE, 'rb')
```

Comment: I call 'pdf_btnClicked()' function but it doesn't work